# Initialization of vector variables in default constructor?

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

How do I initialize private string variables *name* and *age* in my constructor to "John", and 30?

```
class Name_pairs
{
public:
    Name_pairs();
    Name_pairs(string name_cons, double age_cons);
    vector <string> read_names() {return name;};
    vector <double> read_ages() {return age;};
    void print();
    void sort();

private:
    vector <string> name;
    vector <double> age;
};

Name_pairs::Name_pairs()
    : name(), age()
{}
```

The usual :private_variable(default value) doesn't work. Sorry if noobish question, first time encountering classes.

Comment: you don't need vector for name and age if Name_pairs serve for one person only.

Comment: Besides you not needing vectors, just abut *any* book or tutorial should have told you how to initialize member variables in a constructor.

Comment: @Joachim It did, but not if vectors are member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try to initialize the vector name with a string. These are 2 different data types. As billz already suggested, you won't need a vector of strings for a name_pair (or your class naming is misleading for billz and for me).
If you would declare name as a string, you could use the constructor's initialization list again.

```
...
private:
    string name;
    double age;
};

Name_pairs::Name_pairs(string name_cons, double age_cons)
    : name(name_cons), age(age_cons)
...
```

When you have just named your class ambigous and you really need a vector of strings in your class and you only get strings as constructor parameters, you will have to add those strings in the constructors body into your vectors.

```
Name_pairs::Name_pairs(string name_cons, double age_cons)
{
  name.push_back(name_cons);
  age.push_back(age_cons);
}
```

Comment: It's part of the task I'm doing. It could be I misunderstood it, but it does say to use strings as variabbles. This code also works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
Name_pairs::Name_pairs()
    : name( 1, "John" ), age( 1, 30 )
{}
```

Comment: @Luka This creates a vector of length 1 and initializes all elements to `"John"` or `30`, respectively. This makes more sense if your vector is initialized with many elements, but it also works if it's only one.